# Raster calculator with EVI in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, evi

I'm trying to calculate EVI in Arcmap using raster calculator. I put in this calculation

```
2.5 * ((Float("Band4") - "Band3")) / (Float("Band4") + 6 * "Band3" - 7.5 *"Band1" + 1))
```

and the output is syntax error. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You add an extra parenthesis.

Instead of

```
2.5 * ((Float("Band4") - "Band3")) / (Float("Band4") + 6 * "Band3" - 7.5 *"Band1" + 1))
```

It should be

```
2.5 * ((Float("Band4") - "Band3")) / (Float("Band4") + 6 * "Band3" - 7.5 *"Band1" + 1)
```

Or better

```
2.5 * Float("Band4" - "Band3") / (Float("Band4") + 6.0 * Float("Band3") - 7.5 * Float("Band1") + 1.0)
```

Comment: I kind of disagree with your last expression. Wrapping `Float`around the integer addition/subtraction won't stop any integer overflow. Also, if the OP is using Float, that suggests that the data is not reflectance values but digital numbers and EVI needs to be calculated using reflectance.