# Enhanced Vegetation Index( EVI) Value Interpretation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, raster-calculator, landsat, evi

Im working on calculation of Calculation of **Enhanced Vegetation Index(EVI)** From **Landsat 5 TM and Landsat 8 OLI** Using ArcMap 10.4.1. As far i know to Calculate EVI, first it needs to Convert the **DN Values** to Physical **TOA reflectance**. For Landsat 5 TM, I did that steps (First I converted DN to Radiance and then to Reflectance and [image] got the refelectance Values of the required bands ranging between  0 to 1 (**Band 1 =0 to 0.367, Band 3= 0 to 0.648, Band 4= 0 to 0.808**).

Then I applied the Formula for Deriving **EVI= 2.5 * (("Band 4" - "Band 3") / "Band 4" + 6 * "Band 3" - 7.5 * "Band 1" + 1)** in **Raster Calculator** and got result with EVI Ranging **-1822.42 to 12.71** (!) . If i clip my Area of Interest Still get the Value ranges between **-0.658 to +2.95**.

I used to know that EVI ranges between *-1 to +1* , However **USGS** says The **valid** Range is between **-10,000 to +10,000**) see https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/landsat-enhanced-vegetation-index?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con
And i know EVI is  not a Normalized Index like NDVI.

Now I really Want to know if my precedure is okay, and then **how can I interpret The values?** *(eg. Vegetation, Bare Soil etc)*.
And If not then how can I Correctly Calculate **EVI**?

[image]

Comment: Something seems off in your TOA reflectance values. Landsat 5 [TOA reflectance values (p.15)](https://prd-wret.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/palladium/production/atoms/files/LSDS-1370_L4-7_SurfaceReflectance-LEDAPS_ProductGuide-v2.pdf) should range from 0 – 10000. Note that the scale factor is 0.0001 in the documentation that you provide. Here is a similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276959/8104).

Comment: This guide  is about Surface reflectance product, although I'm working with level 1 data (LPGS). I did the Conversion from DN to  reflectance manually with the equation  P' = (Mp * Qcal + Ap)/ sin(¢se) as per given on the USGS website. the reflectance values that i derive from this is quite ok. but when i use the EVI equation in Raster calculator the output result are not satisfactory. Again i also applied the  the scaling factor multiplying the bands by. 0001 and didn't get the expected result. And i also tried the question u gave link here about placing foat, and yet no solution.